# Client call Web Service Timeout

Tags: c#, web-services

I googled so much time but no luck, would you guys please give me a hand?

I have a program that will generate a financial report in PDF and then call a SMTP web service to send emails.

Please find my illustrated code below:

```
using (SMTPServiceSoapClient client = new SMTPServiceSoapClient())
{
    for (no. of customers)
    {
        try
        {
          //step 1: generate_report
          generate_pdf();

          //step 2: call SMTP web service and send email
          client.SendEmail();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The first email always sent successfully.

And the second email will always throw an exception ("The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:24:59.9969997. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.")

And, the success/fail pattern is like

1. success
2. fail
3. success
4. fail

...

Even if i set a very long (e.g. 2 hours) SendTimeOut value. The program will only wait few seconds and then throw an exception.

The below is my app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SMTP ServiceSoap" sendTimeout="00:25:00" maxBufferSize="536870912" maxBufferPoolSize="536870912" maxReceivedMessageSize="536870912" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://smtpsrvhk/SMTPService/SMTPService.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SMTP ServiceSoap"
        contract="SMTPService.SMTPServiceSoap" name="SMTP ServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Please help with thanks.

Below is my code to send emails.

```
        // Email Sending 
        public void sendEmail()
        {
            int result = -999;
            //If Validated
            if (CompareHash() == true)
            {
                MailMessage email = new MailMessage();    

                SmtpClient emailserv = new SmtpClient(SMTPserver);
                emailserv.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(emailserv_SendCompleted);

                //From / To / CC/ Bcc Handling
                MailAddress sendfrom = returnEmailAddress(senderAddr, senderName);
                email.Sender = sendfrom;
                email.From = sendfrom;

                foreach (var to in receipent)
                {
                    email.To.Add(to);
                }
                foreach (var cc in copyToReceipent)
                {
                    email.CC.Add(cc);
                }
                foreach (var bcc in blankcopyToReceipent)
                {
                    email.Bcc.Add(bcc);
                }
                foreach (var reply in replytoReceipent)
                {
                    email.ReplyToList.Add(reply);
                }

                if (ccToSender == true)
                {
                    email.CC.Add(sendfrom);
                }

                if (bccToSender == true)
                {
                    email.Bcc.Add(sendfrom);
                }

                //email.To.Add(sendto);
                email.Subject = EmailTitle;
                email.IsBodyHtml = useHTMLFormat;
                email.Body = EmailContent;

                //Add Attachment If found
                if (attachmentPath.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < attachmentPath.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string fileName = attachmentPath[i];
                        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(fileName);
                        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition;
                        disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(fileName);
                        disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName);
                        disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(fileName);
                        email.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                emailserv.Credentials = null;

                try
                {
                    //emailserv.SendAsync(email, null);
                    emailserv.Send(email);
                    email.Dispose();
                    result = 1;
                    LogDown(result, "Email request has been sent to the SMTP server.");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = -1;
                    LogDown(result, String.Format("Exception during Send, Message:{0}", ex.Message));
                }

            }
            else
            {
                result = -2;
                LogDown(result, "Hash Check Failed");
            }            
            sendResult = result;
        }
```

Comment: can you post the code for sending email ?

Comment: You need to create new client for each email.  Common issue with Net 4.0.  It think this bug has been fixed in Net 4.5 but not sure.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, i tried create new client for each email. The problem still exists.

Comment: @ZweiJames i posted the code for sending email, thanks!

Comment: Did you dispose the mail client before creating new one?  It has been a couple of years since I've seen this issue.  In your SMTP class, make a Dispose() method and make sure you call the dispose.  If I remember correctly with Net 4.0 the only way of disposing the client is to put it in a class and then dispose the class.

Comment: @ZweiJames Also, i tried to send emails without attachments, it works perfectly. However, even i attach a very small size .txt file (15KB), exception will be thrown. I have no idea.

Comment: @jdweng Am i dispose it correctly? MailMessage email = new MailMessage();  //Some Codes//  email.Dispose();

Comment: You need to dispose the client emailserv.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, it might be some network issues between the client and the web service.

It's because i set up the same web service in different location and they worked perfectly.